# Cocoa pods resource bundle xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am using cocoa pods for publishing my code. I do use few png images as image assets and few are pdf vector images for image views. Both png and pdf are under "**image.xcassets**"

My podspec currently specify bundle by using below code

```
    myApp.resource_bundle  = {
        "myApp" => "project/app/Assets/**/*.{storyboard,xib,strings,xcassets}"
    }
```

My question is do since all my png and pdf images are inside image.assets, do i need to specify separately those under resource bundle or since i do specify xcassets it will be taken care. I mean everything under xcassets will be get include?

**solution 1**

```
    myApp.resource_bundle  = {
        "myApp" => "project/app/Assets/**/*.{storyboard,xib,strings,xcassets}"
    }
```

**solution 2**

```
    myApp.resource_bundle  = {
        "myApp" => "project/app/Assets/**/*.{storyboard,xib,strings,xcassets,png,pdf}"
    }
```

which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1** is itself is more than enough to include `xcassets` in the pod. Since it is iOS specific, you can specify it as `myApp.ios.resource_bundle` instead of `myApp.resource_bundle`.

You can find more details on `ios.resource_bundle` [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resource_bundles).

More details on resource_bundle and xcassets can be found [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1892)

You can also [PodAsset](https://cocoapods.org/pods/PodAsset) as a dependency to your podspec to access assets from Pods.

Comment: @kapil, any updates on this? Is your issue resolved?